# How can transparency be toggled?

Tags: frames

I've used the toggle-transparency function from https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TransparentEmacs

```
 (eval-when-compile (require 'cl))
 (defun toggle-transparency ()
   (interactive)
   (if (/=
        (cadr (frame-parameter nil 'alpha))
        100)
       (set-frame-parameter nil 'alpha '(100 100))
     (set-frame-parameter nil 'alpha '(85 50))))
 (global-set-key (kbd "C-c t") 'toggle-transparency)
```

but although this makes the transparency less, it does not completely remove transparency for me (for some reason). I'm on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know whether the following does resolve your problem. Your code has some flaws. Maybe, these cause the dysfunction.

The last sentence of the following section of the [frame parameter documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Font-and-Color-Parameters.html) says that the associated value of `alpha` can also be a number or `nil` (when the window manager should handle transparency).

> ‘alpha’
>       This parameter specifies the opacity of the frame, on graphical
>       displays that support variable opacity.  It should be an integer
>       between 0 and 100, where 0 means completely transparent and 100
>       means completely opaque. It can also have a ‘nil’ value, which
>       tells Emacs not to set the frame opacity (leaving it to the window
>       manager).
>       ...

Your code will error-out in those cases since `cadr` expects a list and `\=` expects numbers as arguments. It handles only the case of the following subsequent section in the doc:

> The alpha frame parameter can also be a cons cell(‘active’ . ‘inactive’),
>      where ‘active’ is the opacity of the frame when it is selected,
>      and ‘inactive’ is the opacity when it is not selected.

There follows a modified function `toggle-transparency` that regards the doc.

```el
(defun toggle-transparency ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((alpha (frame-parameter nil 'alpha)))
    (if (eq
     (if (numberp alpha)
         alpha
       (cdr alpha)) ; may also be nil
     100)
    (set-frame-parameter nil 'alpha '(85 . 50))
      (set-frame-parameter nil 'alpha '(100 . 100)))))
```

Comment: That may be a flaw but the problem was from an outside Ubuntu program when I was trying different ways of making Emacs transparent, I forgot to remove a transparency rule and this was limiting Emac's max transparency. Removing the rule from the Ubuntu program (CompizConfig) fixed it

Comment: Shouldn't the parameters be `(85 . 50)` and `(100 . 100)`, and should be checked with `(cdr alpha)` instead of `cadr`? Though it seems both forms work...

Comment: @npostavs Yes, you are right. The info-manual says so. In my info buffer the manual was badly formatted when I read it. The dot between `active` and `inactive` was at a line end. Therefore I missed it and went mit the OP. I correct it now. Thanks for the notification.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out while I was trying different ways to set transparency, one being CompizConfig which is a Ubuntu program, I had set a rule that emacs would be 96 transparent (4% transparency) so the max emacs could go was that high. After removing the rule I was able to toggle transparency completely.